# How to access 3rd Party cookies in the Browser?

Tags: java, .net, php, javascript, html

How to access  3rd Party cookies in the Browser ?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=third+party+[cookies]

Answer (score 11):

You cant. For security, cookies are limited to access by the domains which posted them.

Comment: But How the browsers can access them?